# How to remove camera source from Chrome Hangouts

Tags: google-chrome, registry, webcam, google-hangouts

I had recently installed Mobiola Webcam and then removed it as well.

But by default chrome thinks its still my webcam. Now my Mic and Cam are both not working in Chrome.  (Windows XP SP2)

It shows "Mobiola Video Source" in settings >> camera source. How to remove it permanently from Chrome.  There is no such plugin by Mobiola Cam too.

I used Video/Audio chat works well in skype - since it understands the cam has been uninstalled already.

Please advise - if there is a registry hack or way to restore previous day chrome settings with plugins etc.

Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

go to registry (regedit) and search {(Find)-(Ctrl+F)} for (Mobiola) u will find one result,delete it. now {(Find Next)-(F3)} and delete it until There are no more result

It Worked for Me 
2016

Comment: hardcore solution, but worked for me for xsplit camera

Comment: Any solutions for macOS?